# Is pos(n) an algorithmic counter?

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, computational-complexity, posets

Let $\ \mathbf N = \{1\ 2\ \ldots\}\ $ be the set of natural numbers. Let $\ f : \mathbf N\rightarrow\mathbf N\ $ be an arbitrary function, and $\ \forall_{n\in\mathbf N}\, F(n)\ :=\ \max_{k = 1\ldots n}\, f(k)$.

Let's assume that, with respect to a fixed universal Turing machine, there exists at least one algorithm which computes $\ f,\ $ and let $\ ||f||_A(n)\ $ be the number of Turing operations which compute $\ f(n)\ $ by algorithm $\ A$.

> By a polynomial $\ \mathbf N\rightarrow\mathbf N\ $ I mean a function which differs from a (true real) polynomial by less then 1 for almost all natural numbers $\ n\in\mathbf N$.

**DEFINITION 1**   Function $\ f\ $ is called a *fast counter* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ there exists an algorithm $\ A\ $ and a polynomial $\ p : \mathbf N\rightarrow \mathbf N\ $ such that

$$\forall_{n\in\mathbf N}\ \ ||f||_A(n)\ \le\ \frac{p(n)}{n!}\cdot F(n) $$

**DEFINITION 2**   Function $\ f\ $ is called a *slow counter* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ for every algorithm $\ A\ $ there exists polynomial $\ q : \mathbf N\rightarrow \mathbf N\ $

$$\forall_{n\in\mathbf N}\ \ ||f||_A(n)\ \ge\ \frac{F(n)}{n!\cdot q(n)}$$

**DEFINITION 3**   Function $\ f\ $ is called an *algorithmic counter* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \ f\ $ is both a fast and a slow counter.

> **QUESTION**   Let $\ pos(n)\ $ be the number of all partial orders in the integer interval $\ \{0\ \ldots\ n\!-\!1\}.\ $ Is function $\ pos\ $ an algorithmic counter?

A similar question holds for the number of quasi-orders (i.e. of topologies).

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this is simply the questions "how fast does the function sending $n$ to the number of partial orders on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ grow?" and "how fast does the function sending $n$ to the number of topologies on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ grow? All this Turing machine stuff must be irrelevant because these functions are trivially bounded by things like $2^{2^n}$ and hence there is no issue with computability. So now you should just work out the answers for $n=1,2,3,4$ and then look up the sequence in OEIS (or just google) and there's your answer, and you can translate it at leisure.

Comment: @znt -- I disagree. Oh, well...

Comment: I certainly might be wrong! I guess for the functions we're talking about I see that there is another issue -- it's not just the growth of the function, it's how long it takes to compute it. So perhaps the question is just "can the functions I'm interested in be computed in polynomial time" or something? What I'm trying to do is to convert the question from what you have written to something which is standard notation for lots of people.

Comment: Wait -- isn't there a theoretical issue here? There is essentially no computable function for which it can be proved that there is *not* an algorithm which computes it in polynomial time -- isn't that right? In other words I'm saying something like -- is *any* example known of a function which is provably not a fast counter?

Comment: @znt - feel free to pose your own MO question. I like mine as it is (but for possible trivial mistyping or similar). My question is an instance of a general topic (which seems new to me) of comparing the values of functions with their complexity. This is natural in the case of functions which count some type of sets or objects. Thus this is in effect an abstract definition of (a class of) counters, i.e. of functions for which the number of objects is not much different from the complexity. I am not writing more because whatever I do on MO I am doomed--saying less is simpler.

Comment: @znt -- (about your theoretical misgivings). Are there impossibility theorems or just our human shortcomings (possibly to be overcome in the future)?

Comment: It's not impossibility theorems -- my understanding is that the reason proving P!=NP is so hard is that it's very difficult to prove that any reasonable problem is not in P, i.e. to rule out the existence of poly time algorithms for, say, a general PSPACE problem (and your problems are surely PSPACE because in both cases we just iterate through the list and count).

Comment: PS a lot will be known about the growth of $f$ and hence $F$ in your examples. First find that out. Then figure out what you're actually asking and it's a question about the complexity of computing $f$ and then you can ask the question you mean to ask without all the obfuscating language.

Comment: @znt, I am not in a business of "obfuscating" anything. I feel that all this time you're missing the point, while you're making progress (I may be wrong of course). Due to your style of communicating, I'll be very glad to follow the OM's suggestion to "avoid extended discussions in comments".

Comment: I assume that, in the definition of $F$, the maximum should be over $k=1,2,\dots,n$.  In particular, if $f$ is non-decreasing (as in the question at the end), then $F=f$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - thank you for pointing to my obnoxious typos. I fixed them.

Comment: I agree with znt in the sense that there are many prerequisites to solving this question that you have not mentioned or addressed. Is this because you tried to find the answers and couldn't? (1) What is the best-known algorithm for computing $pos$? (And to be clear, is $pos$ the same as https://oeis.org/A001035 ?) (2) What are the known upper bounds on the growth rate of $pos$? (3) What are the known lower bounds on the growth rate of $pos$?

Comment: I think that this problem is currently intractable. It is known that
$\mathrm{pos}(n) = 2^{\frac{n^2}{4}+o(n^2)}$. (More accurate estimates
are known but are irrelevant here.) It would be a huge breakthrough to
know whether $\mathrm{pos}(n)$ can be computed in time
$2^{n^{2-\varepsilon}}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @RichardStanley, thank you. I posted the fast counter definition in an easy to read way. I feel that I sacrificed a more exact (and more complicated) formulation. I feel that actually *pos* is just a bit too slow to be a fast counter but only minimally too slow. Anyway, just the *slow* part of my conjecture would mean (if true) that pos(n) cannot be computed in $\ 2^{n^{2-\epsilon}}\ $ time for any $\ \epsilon > 0$.